# Why aren't my dictionary values being updated?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to build a "War" card game in C#.  I use a dictionary Hand which stores the card (e.g., "Ace of Hearts") as the key and the card value (an integer from 2 to 14) as the value.  When I first load the dictionary with cards I don't have the card values and so just store 0's for card values.  Later I attempt to update the card values by performing a lookup on another dictionary.  I obtain the card value and try to update dictionary Hand with the correct card value.  The update doesn't work. The code looks like this:

**Dictionary:**

```
public class Players
{
    public string Player { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Hand { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> card in player1.Hand.ToList())
{
    cardPlayed = card.Key;
    // determine rank of card
    string[] cardPhrases = cardPlayed.Split(' ');
    string cardRank = cardPhrases[0];
    // load card values into dictionary
    Dictionary<string, int> cardValues = new Dictionary<string, int>()      
    {
        {"2", 2},
        {"3", 3},
        {"4", 4},
        {"5", 5},
        {"6", 6},
        {"7", 7},
        {"8", 8},
        {"9", 9},
        {"10", 10},
        {"Jack", 11},
        {"Queen", 12},
        {"King", 13},
        {"Ace", 14}
    };

    int cardValue = cardValues[cardRank];
    // add value to dictionary Hand
    // why isn't this working to update card.Value?          
    player1.Hand[cardPlayed] = cardValue;

    result2 = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", player1.Player, card.Key, card.Value);

    resultLabel.Text += result2;
}
```

When I print out the values as above, card.Value is always 0.

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to make sure the values of `cardPlayed` and `cardValue` are correct?

Comment: Not reproducible. `player1.Hand[cardPlayed] = cardValue` should do exactly as you expect: set the dictionary entry for `player1.Hand[cardPlayed]` to `cardValue`. Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variables. From the code shown it's impossible to analyze this.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue, but you should move cardValues outside your `foreach` loop - you're reinitializing it every time you iterate.  Make it a static member of the class instead...

Comment: I have run it through the debugger, and cardPlayed and cardValue are correct, but when I print out the values as follows:result2 = String.Format("<br />Player: {0} Card: {1} Card Value: {2}", player1.Player, card.Key, card.Value);
               
               ;
                resultLabel.Text += result2;  Card.Value is always 0.

Comment: Can you show the code for player1.Hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have run it through the debugger, and cardPlayed and cardValue are correct, but when I print out the values [...] card.Value is always 0.

Because `card.Value` is from `player1.Hand.ToList()`, which contain the dictionary entries *before* you set them. `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a struct.

You need to print `player1.Hand[cardPlayed]`.

See the following code (http://ideone.com/PW1F4o):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 0, "Foo"}
        };

        foreach (var kvp in dict.ToList())
        {
            dict[kvp.Key] = "Bar";

            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value); // Foo (the initial value)
            Console.WriteLine(dict[kvp.Key]); // Bar (the value that was set)
        }
    }
}
```